# Android AndEngine play sound once only

Tags: android, andengine

My code below is in the scene's `registerupdatehandler` ..

```
if (B.collidesWith(l)){ 
                                            mSound.play();
                                        }
```

currently, it gets play again and again until the `B` gets away from the `l` (not colliding).

**update:**

```
                /* The actual collision-checking. */
                mScene.registerUpdateHandler(new IUpdateHandler() {
                    @Override
                    public void reset() {
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onUpdate(final float pSecondsElapsed) {

                        if (B.collidesWith(l)){ 
                                    if (!mHasPlayed) {
                                        Log.i("CONTACT", "BETWEEN B and L!");
                                        mSound.play();
                                        mHasPlayed = true;
                                    } else {
                                        mHasPlayed = false;
                                    }
                                }
                            }


                });
```

Answer (score 3):

Keep track if you have played the sound for this collision event yet with a member variable.

```
private boolean mHasPlayed = false;

// ... rest of code

if (B.collidesWith(l)) {
    if (!mHasPlayed)
        mSound.play();

    mHasPlayed = true;
} else {
    mHasPlayed = false;
}
```

Comment: Add a logcat to the `else` portion and see if that is getting called in between to reset `mHasPlayed`.

Comment: it gets called 5 times same as the other logcat, both 5 times .. so the sound gets to play 5 times

Comment: Can you post how you are updating the position of `B`? I think that might have something to do with this. It seems like the results of `collidesWith()` are not reliable right now.

Comment: B gets to move with a path modifier .. and the l is a line in the middle .. see this picture https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/48748692/456456.jpg .. The black line is the path the B moves along and the red line is "l"

Comment: I'm afraid I'm out of suggestions... Sorry man. Try debugging it and stepping into `B.collidesWith()` to see if you can find something obvious about why it is returning `false` when `B` is still colliding with `l`. If you stumble upon something and need help figuring it out, feel free to update your question and I will do what I can.

Comment: thanks very much, your efforts were enough. upvoted.